# How to show the content type diffrent types in a block?

Tags: views, 7

I have a news website, I have one content-type what named **news**, news has some fields like:

> news_title
>
> news_date
>
> images
>
> body
>
> news_type

I want each news type shows in a block dynamically, my news_types are **Sport, Economy, Political, Health** and some others. and I want each of this shows in one block, is there any way is view or even in content-type settings to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create multiple blocks for different news types. Once you creates blocks using views, assign them to regions from Admin -> Structure -> Blocks.